How to auto accept Y in CMD prompt when running a powershell script
I am trying to run a powershell script (.ps1) to automatically install some Python libraries on a remote server. I am using the conda package manager and the powershell start-process command. The problem I am encountering is that when it runs this way, a cmd prompt gets launched that requires an accept Y/N response before it will complete. The commands look like this:
$conda_server = "C:\Program Files\<extrapolate software where conda is install>\bin\Python\Scripts\conda.exe"
#Add USTopo POD specific libraries
start-process $conda_server -Wait -ArgumentList "install pathlib"

When I run it inside the server manually, this (see below) is what happens. I am already running this with elevated/admin permission, so that is not a consideration.
I have tried the following, which didn't work.
echo y | start-process $conda_server -Wait -ArgumentList "install pathlib" 

What tags or commands can I add that will allow me to automatically accept/enter Y when this runs so that my script doesn't get hung up? :


Does this answer your question: $conda_server install -y pathlib?

Have you looked at the conda install command? Your use case may be a situation for which using --yes might be appropriate.

cmd /c "echo y | $conda_server install pathlib"
